# Android Manifest attributes depending on SDK version

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, scoped-storage

Android 11 introduces various privacy changes including [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage). This implies that on Android 11 or higher, the app no longer

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But I still need to maintain the feature on Android 10 or lower. Is it possible to declare Manifest permissions and attributes depending on the SDK version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element) :

```
<uses-permission android:name="string"
    android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

`android:maxSdkVersion`

> The highest API level at which this permission should be granted to
> your app. Setting this attribute is useful if the permission your app
> requires is no longer needed beginning at a certain API level. For
> example, beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), it's no longer
> necessary for your app to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> permission when your app wants to write to its own
> application-specific directories on external storage (the directories
> provided by getExternalFilesDir()). However, the permission is
> required for API level 18 and lower. So you can declare that this
> permission is needed only up to API level 18 with a declaration such
> as this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

So your `maxSdkVersion` would be `28` (as apps on Android 10/ API level 29 or up don't need to request it). Your question mentions Android 11 but reading the documentation it seems its allowed from Android 10 and up.

Comment: Updated my answer I linked to the wrong thing for your specific issue

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw, my `maxSdkVersion` would be 29 thanks to the attribute         `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Comment: My app is already targeting Android 11, but can I continue to declare the "requestLegacyExternalStorage" attribute in the manifest? Or is it against google play policies? i had taken it out and now it is not working to save files on android 10 when i declare it works.